# Htaccess Unable to redirect all pages to HTTP except one

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have tried all the solutions I've come across but I can't seem to get this working properly, I have a WP site and want all pages forced to HTTP other than /payments which I need forced to HTTPS.

Getting the payments page forced to HTTPS works but all the solutions I've tried to get the force HTTP end up redirecting /payments to the site root.

This is what my htaccess looks like ***UPDATED***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/payments/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^payments/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You need to remove the leading slash from rule's pattern : 

    `RewriteRule ^payments/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks but I still get redirected to my homepage when I do that.